# GCP Compute Engine - cannot listen on port 80?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I created a compute engine which has these network tags and firewall rules:
[image]

[image]
So if I understand this correctly, **the machine is allowed to listen on port 80**.
I installed node and created a really simple http server just to see if I can reach the box via http. Logged in via ssh on cloud console. When I try to start it (e.g. `npm start` to run the server), it says:

`Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 0.0.0.0:80`

Why? How to resolve?

I read somewhere that low port #s are usually restricted to root user, so I tried `sudo` it says `sudo: npm: command` not found and similar for sudo node.

Also why is that when you create a server [using scripts like these](https://medium.com/google-cloud/manage-google-compute-engine-with-node-js-eef8e7a111b4), the article says they are executed as root? How does that happen and why am I not executing as root when I'm the one who booted up the machine and logged in as myself? Yes, my understanding of linux perms is very newbie.

Thanks...

Comment: Did you add http-server tag to the network tags of your instance?

Comment: @EmreSülün I don't recall coming across anything called 'network tags' during creation. Where do I find this flag now, that the VM has already been created? I'll go look in gcp see if i can find something like this... UPDATE: yes I did. Updating images in Q.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to use TCP ports lower than 1024 you node server must run with root privileges. TCP ports 1024 and higher do not require privilege.

When you login to a Google Cloud Compute Engine instance, you are loggin in as a `normal` user. You do not have root privilege. To grant root privilege to a command, prefix it with `sudo`. Example: `sudo mkdir /directoryname`.

I do **NOT** recommend running node servers with root privilege. This opens a possibly serious security hole in your system. Search the Internet on this topic before deciding.

Your choices are:

1. Select a port above 1023. Common port numbers: 8000, 8080, 5000.
2. Start the node server with root privileges: `sudo node hello.js`

In regards to npm not being found. You will need to modify the environment's PATH variable to include the location of where you installed your node toolset for the user `root`.

Comment: he can also run a reverse proxy like nginx, proxy that port for a domain.

Comment: Correct. Run the node server above port 1023 as a normal user and use a load balancer, proxy server, etc. to map the node port to port 80.

Comment: Another item. Web services provide by tiny servers like node, Flask, etc are not designed to be reliable. They are designed to provide `micro-services`. They are designed to be started and killed at any time. They are very useful in `containers`, `kubernetes`, etc. They are `problematic` at best on normal compute instances as servers.

Comment: Exactly, using a reverse proxy like nginx, traefik or if running kubernetes using ingress (which itself uses reverse proxies as a controller) is much more reliable.

Comment: Tho, if services being killed is a problem then he can use something like `pm2` or `forever`, that restart the services as soon as they exit.

Comment: Reverse proxies are NOT more reliable as a system. If the backend (node server) fails, then the reverse proxy will not be able to serve requests.

Comment: Unless `pm2` or `forever` are performing healthchecks, they don't add anything to the reliability equation. They just keep a process running in the background. They don't detect failures.

Comment: Yeah but if specified, they can atleast show up an error message while the server is being restarted instead of an "This site can’t be reached"

Comment: @JohnHanley, DakshMiglani, I don't know about microservices and kubernetes or nginx yet. I am just a nodejs dev learning how to use gcp. Good to know about types of services not good for reliable stuff. I am just learning: this server will do next to nothing. I just got stuck cos I couldn't run it. Will use diff port and accept ans thx.

Comment: @JohnHanley tho, i think pm2 does have a health check module.

Comment: @yen - just use port 8000 or 8080, which are very common. Develop and learn. Then worry about load balancers, reverse proxies, containers, etc.